# How to run a infinite loop but use less memory in python

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to write a script that receives data from Redis then do something. For now, the only solution that comes out from my head is to let python run an infinite loop to check a Key value is changed or not. But in this scenario, I am not sure using a while loop is a 'memory-lesser' way to achieve this... Is there a better solution to do the same work?

```
while True:

    value = client.get('key').decode('ascii')

    while value == 'go':
        print('going!!')
        #founction 1
        value = client.get('key').decode('ascii')

    while value =='stop':
        print('watting response...')
        #founction 2
        value = client.get('key').decode('ascii')
```

Basically, I'm writing an ADB script to let my phone do stuff like edit photos and send messages. I want to build up something like a server to send signals to tell the script what to do. I built a Tornado server and when I click buttons on the webpage, it can run python scripts through the os command. But I want to figure out is there a way that I can keep my script keeps running in background while waiting for the signal(from Redis or any other tools/servers), also in low usage of CPU and memory.

Comment: Why do you think the loop will consume memory? Python has a garbage collector, so at every iteration you override the names and the old values will be garbage collected, so the memory should remain pretty constant unless you do something that keeps stuff alive, but the code as you have shown here does not do that.

Comment: Is it really _memory_ your concerned with?  There's no inherent reason a loop like that would consume any meaningful amount of memory.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you are doing too many requests to Redis and it's unclear why do you need them?

Comment: You should not be using much more memory than what python itself requires (for the code above).  Obviously it will ultimately depend on what else you do during the iterations.  For CPU usage, I'm not a redis user, so I don't know if they have a subscribe capability so that you could just wait for an event instead of polling for it.  But if you are going to poll, adding some sort of sleep to any while loop should keep your CPU usage manageable.  Or if it's a network redis, it will keep your network usage manageable.